# Jquery accordion onchange

Tags: jquery, database, jquery-ui

I have an issue with some JQuery code that I am trying to run. Basically, I have a list of people formatted as a JQuery ui accordion and I want to display the selected person's picture beside the accordion. Then, when there is a change in the accordion selection, I want the new person's picture to load from a database, as well as some other information. Has anyone had experience with JQuery events and accessing databases?

Comment: And what is this code you're talking about ?

Answer (score 0):

In fact, this question is not very precise : how do you access your database? Via PHP / ASP.NET and which database is it?

But, here is some hint on how I make such things: you first have to bind change event of the accordion with some AJAX request querying your database via some handler page. Thus in your javascript code, you will have something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $("#accordion").accordion({
        change: function(event, ui) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'handler.php',
                dataType: "json",
                data: { id: ui.newHeader.text() }, // send the user id for which we want informations
                success: function(data) { 
                    // Update of the new accordion line
                    ui.newContent.find("img").attr("src", data.userImage); 
                }
            })
        }
    });
});
```

and the page handler.php which deals with let's say a MySQL database :

```
/// Connexion to the database
$db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'login', 'password'); 
mysql_select_db('database',$db); 

// Query for retrieving data associated with the user
$query = mysql_query("SELECT imgSrc FROM users WHERE id = " . $_POST['id']);
$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($query )) {
    $rows[] = $r['imgSrc'];
}

// Send the data to user
return json_encode($rows);
```